# Decrease loading time between init and viewDidLoad in a UIViewController?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller

In improving the performance of my app, I'm trying to decrease the amount of time it takes for a UIViewController to load and appear. I've tagged each of my methods to log how long it takes for each to load (this was done on an old iPhone 4 to exaggerate the times).

```
2013-07-03 15:50:32.546 MyApp[3047:907] init begin
2013-07-03 15:50:32.590 MyApp[3047:907] init end
2013-07-03 15:50:33.085 MyApp[3047:907] viewDidLoad begin
2013-07-03 15:50:33.194 MyApp[3047:907] viewDidLoad end
```

As you can see, there's about 0.5 seconds between init ends and viewDidLoad begins. To my understanding, this is where loadView occurs, but I'm not really touching that at all.

My question is: what is the best practice for decreasing the amount of loading time here? Is there anything I am able to do programmatically, or is it strictly the limitation of the device?

---

**EDIT:**

Some code:

```
MyViewController *myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *myNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myViewController];
myNavController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;

[myNavController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
[self presentViewController:myNavController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Some more time logs:

```
2013-07-03 21:07:26.813 MyApp[3612:907] begin presentViewController:animated:completion
2013-07-03 21:07:27.292 MyApp[3612:907] begin viewDidLoad
2013-07-03 21:07:27.401 MyApp[3612:907] finish viewDidLoad
2013-07-03 21:07:27.444 MyApp[3612:907] finish presentViewController:animated:completion
2013-07-03 21:07:27.508 MyApp[3612:907] begin loading tableView
2013-07-03 21:07:27.760 MyApp[3612:907] finish loading tableView
2013-07-03 21:07:28.513 MyApp[3612:907] viewDidAppear
```

My view controller is loaded from a NIB and contains a tableView and a UIDatePicker. There seems to be this 0.5 second gap between begin presentViewController:animated:completion and begin viewDidLoad. Since I don't have any code here, I don't know where/how to even approach reducing this time, or if it's even possible.

Comment: Please show some code.

Answer (score 3):

Logging output has an impact on performance. This is probably a lot quicker without those log output statements.

However, is this really the slowest area of your code when you run it through instruments time profiler? I doubt that.

Profile your code and concentrate on increasing the performance of the biggest bottlenecks first.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I edited my original post to show some code. Further inspection with the time profiler led me to presentViewController:animated:completion being the primary bottleneck (about 600 ms). Most of the time is spent transitioning and displaying the view controller, while my customization in viewDidLoad has minimal impact.

Comment: With that said, is there anything that can be done to reduce this time?

Comment: Assuming that you haven't added any code that you are not showing here that would hinder performance, then creating a UIViewController and adding it to a UINavigationController and presenting it shouldn't need to be optimised, and I highly doubt anyone is trying to optimise this standard usage.

Comment: I included more time logs in my original post. Creating the view and navigation controllers are instantaneous. The main bottleneck (~0.5s) is right after I call presentViewController:animated:completion and right before my customization in viewDidLoad occurs. Since I don't have any other code here, I don't know where/how to even approach reducing this time, or if it's even possible at all. My view controller is loaded from a NIB and contains a tableView and a UIDatePicker, but to my understanding those load instantaneously as well during init().

Comment: Nibs don't load during init and they don't load instantaneously, they are read from disk after all - so there is nothing instant about that.  The nib would be loaded when the view controllers view property is accessed for the first time. You could certainly improve performance by not using nib files.

Answer (score 0):

Recommend performing task which takes longer task on background thread but keep in mind UI specific needs to be done on main thread as UIKit components are not thread safe.

For instance, if you are showing image on image view, which are loaded initially from internet, the loading task has to be done on background thread and once the image's data is loaded, render it on main thread.

The methods you have mentioned above are view controller's life cycle which gives you flexibility in defining what you can implement at that very specific situation. For instance, in init, you can initialise all your instance variables, on viewDidLoad, you can setup your components, and there is another method which gets called viewWillAppear, everytime when view appears and disappears, a place for setting and resetting delegates, notifications, observers and others.

And there are other methods such as viewDidAppear, viewDidDisappear, viewDidUnload(deprecated from iOS 6.0) and others to handle view controller's life cycle events, in other states to control and manage view controller's states.

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading images from the internet with large size you can use lazy loading which puts an initial image until the image is loaded and this will help the view appear faster.